# Taller Saved Sessions box in PuTTY

Tags: connection, putty

I'd love to be able to set the size of my Portable [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) Configuration window's Saved Sessions box so that I can see all of my Saved Sessions without scrolling.

Are there any versions of PuTTY that just have a taller or configurable Saved Sessions box?  I'm not looking for PuTTY Connection Manager or versions of putty like that that are vastly different.  I like the simplicity of the original :).

[image: putty screenshot pulled from the web]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kitty is similar enough to *keep you comfortable*, and different enough to provide exactly what you asked for  :o)

http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?page=Sessions%20filter&zone=en

Note: This picture only shows part of the GUI, the rest looks almost the same as PuTTY

[image]